# cannot find symbol method withSSECustomerKey(SSECustomerKey)

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using Amazon S3 to upload content for users in my android app, of course data should be encrypted on amazon server because it is private for users.
From my application, users should be able to view their data online (without downloading to device).

I found that using `SSECustomerKey` will meet the requirements but i cannot make it work, it always give the error :

> cannot find symbol method withSSECustomerKey(SSECustomerKey)

I imported `com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.SSECustomerKey;` and the code itself doesn't give any errors, but it won't build.

I am using aws-android-sdk-s3-2.2.11.jar
I am using Android studio 1.5.1

```
SSECustomerKey customerKey = Constants.getCustomerKey(mContext);

public static SSECustomerKey getCustomerKey(Context context) {

        SSECustomerKey sseKey = null;
        String preferenceKey = PreferenceData.getStringPref(PreferenceData.KEY_ENCRYPTION, context);

        if ( preferenceKey != null) {
            // decode the base64 encoded string
            byte[] decodedKey = Base64.decodeBase64(preferenceKey.getBytes());
            // rebuild key using SecretKeySpec
            SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, 0, decodedKey.length, "AES");
            sseKey = new SSECustomerKey(originalKey);
            return sseKey;
        } else {
            try {
                SecretKey symKey = generateSecretKey();
                // get base64 encoded version of the key
                String encodedKey = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(symKey.getEncoded()));
                System.out.println("key_string encoded: " + encodedKey);
                sseKey = new SSECustomerKey(symKey);
                PreferenceData.setStringPref(PreferenceData.KEY_ENCRYPTION, context, encodedKey);
                return sseKey;
            } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
                System.out.println("Caught an AmazonServiceException, which " +
                        "means your request made it " +
                        "to Amazon S3, but was rejected with an error response" +
                        " for some reason.");
                System.out.println("Error Message:    " + ase.getMessage());
                System.out.println("HTTP Status Code: " + ase.getStatusCode());
                System.out.println("AWS Error Code:   " + ase.getErrorCode());
                System.out.println("Error Type:       " + ase.getErrorType());
                System.out.println("Request ID:       " + ase.getRequestId());
            } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
                System.out.println("Caught an AmazonClientException, which " +
                        "means the client encountered " +
                        "an internal error while trying to " +
                        "communicate with S3, " +
                        "such as not being able to access the network.");
                System.out.println("Error Message: " + ace.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return sseKey;
    }

    private static SecretKey generateSecretKey() {
        try {
            KeyGenerator generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            generator.init(256, new SecureRandom());
            return generator.generateKey();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
            return null;
        }
    }

PutObjectRequest uploadRequest = new PutObjectRequest(Constants.BUCKET_NAME, key, mediaFileToUpload);
                            uploadRequest.withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
                            uploadRequest.withSSECustomerKey(customerKey);//error
```

This is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    afterEvaluate {
        tasks.matching {
            it.name.startsWith('dex')
        }.each { dx ->
            if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
                dx.additionalParameters = ['--multi-dex']
            } else {
                dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
            }
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xx.xx"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    //    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-1.7.1.1.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-s3-2.2.11.jar')
}
```

Comment: Would you show your code and stack trace? What SDK are you using?

Comment: @Yangfan I edited my post and added code.

Comment: What do you meant by "it won't build"? Do you see any build error? Does it run? Anything in stacktrace?

Comment: @Yangfan i am sorry i mean it builds successfully but when i run it, it gives this error only : 'cannot find symbol method withSSECustomerKey(SSECustomerKey)'

Comment: Possible causes are: 1. aws-mobile-sdk-s3 jar isn't exported to the app (if you use Eclipse); 2. proguard isn't configured correctly and the method is pruned. I believe it has something to do with your project setup. Would you please share your IDE info, gradle build script and stack trace?

Comment: @Yangfan I am using Android studio 1.5.1, i edited my post and added build.gradle